# Best practices: Folder structure for client and server using create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Recently I've done a few small projects with a Node backend and a React frontend using create-react-app. Although I've spent quite a bit of time researching best practices for folder structures I haven't been able to come up with a satisfying solution without having to eject the react app. I wonder if there are solutions out there that I just haven't found yet.

The folder structure I am trying to aim for looks something like this:

```
package.json
src/
   client/
     app.js
     ...
   server/
   index.js (node.js main file, could just as well be in server/)
```

This layout would allow me to run all scripts from the root folder and I can put all configurations in one package.json. For example, I would like to be able to just run `npm test` from the root folder which would then use jest to run both the client and the server tests.

As far as I can tell create-react-app is hardwired to expect a `src/index.js` when using `npm start`, which prevents me from using this folder structure - if I just move all the boilerplate generated by create-react-app into the client folder I have an ugly `src/client/src` folder which again contains it's own package.json. I guess I could split it differently, creating a `client/src` and `server/src`, but I still have separate package.json files in each directory.

Would love the hear about your experiences with this, maybe I am missing the obvious solution.

Comment: Since Node app doesn't have to deal with CRA except that it expects a bundle to be placed to public folder, there's no reason to keep Node app under CRA project.

Answer (score 10):

```
   mainDir/
      app/
        src/
          index.js
        package.json
      api/
        src/
          index.js
        package.json
```

I follow this pattern for developing applications in microservice architecture.

This structure is for mono-repos.

You also can divide the front end and backend into different repositories.