# npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/client/package.json'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, enoent

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to re-deploy this project and for some reason it won't run the way I wanted after doing some updates. I'm on React version 18 and Node v21.6. Here's my folder structure:
fnrc(main folder):
-client
-server
-package.json

I'm using Concurrently to run both subfolders. When I try to npm run dev on my main folder(fnrc), it gives me this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsf8r.png)

```
    > fnrc@1.0.0 dev
> concurrently "npm run client" "nodemon server.js"

[1] [nodemon] 3.0.3
[1] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[1] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[1] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[1] [nodemon] starting `node server.js index.js`
[1] node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152
[1]   throw err;
[1]   ^
[1] 
[1] Error: Cannot find module '/Users/neilsolon/Documents/4mac/Website/fnrc/index.js'
[1]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
[1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
[1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
[1]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
[1]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[1]   requireStack: []
[1] }
[1] 
[1] Node.js v21.6.0
[1] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[0] 
[0] > fnrc@1.0.0 client
[0] > npm start --prefix /client
[0] 
[0] npm ERR! code ENOENT
[0] npm ERR! syscall open
[0] npm ERR! path /client/package.json
[0] npm ERR! errno -2
[0] npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/client/package.json'
[0] npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
[0] npm ERR! enoent 
[0] 
[0] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/neilsolon/.npm/_logs/2024-01-28T03_14_54_746Z-debug-0.log
[0] npm run client exited with code 254
```

But when I cd into my client subfolder and npm run dev(with the "dev" script) or npm run start(without the "dev" script) it somehow works.

Here's my package.json of my main folder:

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv3NB.png)

```
    `{
  "dependencies": {
    "audit": "^0.0.6",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "fix": "^0.0.3",
    "npm": "^10.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "client": "npm start --prefix /client",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"nodemon server.js\"" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}`
```

My client subfolder:
[client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwuJe.png)

```
`enter code here{
  "name": "nfrc",
  "homepage": "https://fnrc.ca",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.8",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-snap": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "react-snap",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}`
```

My server subfolder:

[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/129O2.png)

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "npm start --prefix /client",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"nodemon server.js\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.10",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

I tried to remove package-lock.json and node_modules in my main folder, npm clear cache, and npm install. No luck.

Hopefully you guys can help me out so I can `npm run build` this. Thanks in advance!

I updated the dependencies and React and NodeJS versions. I removed package-lock json and node_modules in my main folder and then npm install. I also tried npm init.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Neil.  Your question will be better received if you can create your folder structure within the question.  Providing links to images or other site is generally discouraged because those links may break in the future and then your question and it's answers will not be beneficial to others seeking help to the same problem you're having.  Consider editing your question to include these extra details.

Comment: Noted. Edited now. Thanks for the tip @JerrenSaunders.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message screenshot. It looks like there's no *package.json* in the client folder.

[Best practices: Folder structure for client and server using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741684/11950988)

I'm new to coding also, hope this helps

Inside you main *package.json*, remove the `/` before client. Replace line 11 with `"client": "npm start --prefix client"`. This will assume that the client directory is directly inside the root directory.

**Reference links for eslint conflict error**[Edited]

[Plugin “react” was conflicted between “package.json » eslint-config-react-app](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plugin-react-was-conflicted-between-package-json-eslint-config-react-app/)

[Issues#4186](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/issues/4186#issuecomment-997500192)

Comment: Thanks. But I do have a package.json in that folder which is weird.

Comment: I see. I hope the edited (second solution) will be helpful

Comment: Awesome! It worked. I just didn't implement it on both package.jsons. Thanks a lot! my problem now is when I try to npm run build it won't detect my index.html in my public folder. I revised my script to "build": "cd client && react-scripts build". It returned this error: [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » /Users/neilsolon/Documents/4mac/Website/fnrc/client/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js" and "BaseConfig » /Users/neilsolon/Documents/4mac/Website/fnrc/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js". Any suggestion?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error, sorry. But you might find the two links I added helpful. It seems like it's issue that has been recognized. @Neil

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was finally able to resolve it. It took a few tries of re-installing/updating some dependencies and was finally able to build.